# cvFindContours() not detecting separate components

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I'm trying to find connected components present (if any) within a small region of an image. However the cvFindContours() function is grouping visibly separate components into one single component making further calculations incorrect.

How do I get the separate components within the region? (Colored different components as detected by the function).

The code is as follows:

```
    IplImage* cc_img = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(src), src->depth, 3 );
cvSetZero(cc_img);
CvScalar(ext_color);

CvMemStorage *mem;
mem = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
CvSeq *contours = 0;
CvSeq *ptr;
int n_cont = 0;
int n = cvFindContours( src, mem, &contours, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0));

for (ptr = contours; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->h_next) 
{
    n_cont++;

    ext_color = CV_RGB( rand()&255, rand()&255, rand()&255 ); //randomly coloring different contours
    cvDrawContours(cc_img, ptr, ext_color, CV_RGB(0,0,0), -1, CV_FILLED, 8, cvPoint(0,0));        
}
```

[image]

"CEL" is considered to be a single component!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use OpenCV, but I verified with Mathematica that you probably want to specify that two components should be connected only through their top, bottom, left, and right neighbors. If you consider the full 8 neighbors, then all the three letters are connected, as you showed:

```
comp = MorphologicalComponents[img, CornerNeighbors -> False];
Colorize[comp]
```

[image]

Comment: basically change the 8-connected to 4-connected neighbors. ok, will see if there's a way to modify the `CvFindContours` that way

Answer (score 1):

Try applying some morphological filtering such as `cvErode` or `cvMorphologyEx(..., CV_MOP_OPEN)` to expand the distance between the letters before running `cvFindContours`.

Comment: that would distort the letters themselves. the subsequent code wouldn't work then. Though a thinning operation might work. ... any way to modify the cvFindContours() to make it detect correctly?

Comment: Not that I know of...I've run into a similar problem and hacked around it by finding the connected components on the eroded image, then going back and masking off pixels in the original image and re-running cvFindContours() on the masked image to get it right.

Comment: now that sounds good; i'm onto it. Could you be a bit more detailed about the going back and masking: which pixels are masked in the original image?

Comment: Hi, Did you find an answer to the problem? I am encountering the same problem and out of ideas on what can be done. Please help!